# Как не сломать компьютер учась низкоуровневому программированию?

Tags: windows, ассемблер

При вызове какого нибудь прерывания боюсь сломать комп) Есть ли какой-нибудь аналог песочницы для таких развлечений?

Comment: Любая виртуальная машина?

Comment: там ломать особо не чего. можете случайно что то стереть на диске, например загрузочный сектор или говорят сжечь видеокарту, но это надо оооочень сильно постараться, случайно, да еще прерываниям вряд ли выйдет

Answer (score 3):

В университете, на курсе микропрограммирования, мы использовали Virtual Box. А так - любая виртуальная машина

Answer (score 1):

**Важно устанавливать 32 бит операционную систему если вы будете запускать .com 
 файл**

---

## Посоветую несколько виртуальных машин

- #### VirtualBox

  Подходит для начала, дальше если вам нужна автоматизация то QEMU
- #### QEMU

  Идеален для таких целей, особенно если вы будете писать загрузчик. Автоматизация происходит путем .sh (linux, mac) или .bat (window) файлов. Сначала покажется непонятным но потом не откажитесь :)
- #### Vmware

  Если честно меня не очень порадовал: цена и практически никаких отличий от VB разве что поддержка Windows 7 и Vista aero, но это все свистелки.
- #### Parallels Desktop

  Я им не пользовался, не могу сказать, но если у тебя мак стоит попробовать.
- #### bochs

  свободная программа для эмуляции аппаратного обеспечения IBM PC.

---

Для новичка посоветую VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

Может быть подойдёт [Oracle VM VirtualBox](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html)?